# How to save intermediate files from tensorflow build?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm attempting to analyze the pre-processed source for tensorflow's op kernels. I tried the following command line, adapted from the general build instructions:

```
 bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --save_temps
```

It builds correctly, but from the documentation, I was expecting another pass with -H / -S passed to the compilers. I'm not sure if this happened, but I can't find any .i, .ii, or .s files for any but a handful of files (I see .i files for swig and .s files for boringssl and nsync) in my cache folder, though I do get .i files for the sources to the python package:

```
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/local_computation_builder.i
./tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/xla.i
./tensorflow/python/training/server_lib.i
./tensorflow/python/training/quantize_training.i
./tensorflow/python/grappler/item.i
./tensorflow/python/grappler/cost_analyzer.i
./tensorflow/python/grappler/tf_optimizer.i
./tensorflow/python/grappler/model_analyzer.i
./tensorflow/python/grappler/cluster.i
./tensorflow/python/pywrap_tfe.i
./tensorflow/python/lib/io/py_record_writer.i
```

Suspecting that I might need to build a different target, I attempted to list the available targets:

```
bazel query //tensorflow --output package
```

but ran into the following error:

```
WARNING: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f4653201e29159237cbc73869b47a72b/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f4653201e29159237cbc73869b47a72b/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a build error in future versions
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tf-persist/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1166
    _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
File "/tf-persist/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1014, in _create_local_cuda_repository
    _find_libs(repository_ctx, cuda_config)
File "/tf-persist/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 667, in _find_libs
    _find_cuda_lib("cudnn", repository_ctx, cpu_value, cu..., ...)
File "/tf-persist/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 587, in _find_cuda_lib
    auto_configure_fail(("Cannot find cuda library %s" %...))
File "/tf-persist/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 210, in auto_configure_fail
    fail(("\n%sCuda Configuration Error:%...)))

Cuda Configuration Error: Cannot find cuda library libcudnn.so.7
```

If it's not clear, I'm not very familiar with bazel.

Questions:

A) Am I correct in my diagnosis of the problem? If so, am I querying the target list correctly?

B) Can I generate intermediate representations with bazel without actually compiling the source? I don't actually need the object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`--save_temps`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--save_temps) only works for the target Bazel is explicitly building, it doesn't work for all transitive dependencies. So you have to find a C++ target that you're interested in and build it directly. Then you'll see a bunch of `.ii` and `.s` files.

Side track, you can run your build with [`--subcommands`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--subcommands) to see all the actions and command lines that Bazel creates.

Re query, `bazel query //tensorflow/...` works for me, is it possible that the error is caused by sync-out of sources and ./configure? It looks like a configuration issue. I didn't try building TF with cuda support enabled.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. I found the Makefile in contrib and that looks like a more viable option, though I'm not sure it's worth the hassle over simply dumping the asm from the compiled binaries at this point.